# Problem: Dataset's date-time showing differently in Kaggle vs. my original RMarkdown file

Tags: r, kaggle

I am an aspiring R User, who is having a unique 'translation' issue when I transfer my RMarkdown file into Kaggle:

I am attempting to post my first Case Study that uses a Kaggle dataset. I've gotten all my other work to "translate" correctly, except for one problem.

I utilized a csv file Dataset from Kaggle, which contains a date-time column (ActivityHour), and the initial RStudio 'glimpse' is correctly showing the time portion in military time.

```
glimpse(hourly_steps)
Rows: 22,099
Columns: 3
$ Id 1503960366, 1503960366, 1503960366, 1503960366, 150396036…
$ ActivityHour "4/12/2016 0:00", "4/12/2016 1:00", "4/12/2016 2:00", "4/…
$ StepTotal 373, 160, 151, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 250, 1864, 676, 360, 253, 2…
```

I then coded to split off the time for a data visualization, successfully in RStudio/RMarkdown. My plot shows 24 entries for all hours of the day, thanks to the military time.

However, once I load the RMarkdown work to Kaggle, from the start, the initial 'glimpse' of the csv file is instead showing the ActivityHour date-time in AM/PM.

```
glimpse(hourly_steps)
Rows: 22,099
Columns: 3
$ Id 1503960366, 1503960366, 1503960366, 1503960366, 150396036…
$ ActivityHour "4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 1:00:00 AM", "4/12/20…
$ StepTotal 373, 160, 151, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 250, 1864, 676, 360, 253, 2…
```

This is throwing off my data visualization portion of my RMarkdown file, and grouping together the AM's and PM's, for only 12 entries in my plot.

I am hoping for an easy fix! Does anyone have an explanation for how this occurs in Kaggle? If needed, I can provide more details. Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(hourly_steps)` as well as the code for an example of the visualization you mention.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Kudos for including details in your question, though for others who might want to try to reproduce your issue,  there are still many pieces missing. Best would be starting with actual raw data samples you are working on, from you local systems as well as from Kaggle, ideally a few rows from CSV files. Less ideal would be referring to Kaggle dataset and file, it's not encouraged as Kaggle login is required and off-site links are also prone to link-rot, but it would still beat the guesswork.

Comment: By any chance, is it `hourlySteps_merged.csv` from https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/arashnic/fitbit ? If yes, it seems that you have either skipped a parsing step in Kaggle or even used a different dataset for your local work -- line sample from the csv matches to what you see in Kaggle: `1503960366,4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM,373` .  In most cases you'd want to parse this value as  a datetime instead of splitting strings. And that `glimpse() ` output also looks strange, it should include actual variable types, i.e. `$ ActivityHour <chr> "4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 1:00:00 AM", "4/12/20…`

Comment: thank you for the feedback.  that is the dataset that i'm using, i've linked my project directly to the dataset.  When I download the csv and open the file, the date-time column is showing military time for my file, and i believe that's why i am seeing a successful plot once i process my file...
here is the roundabout method i used to get to my Plot in RSTUDIO.  not pretty, but again, I'm very to new to this and cobbled together a method to get the time split into a proper "00:00:00" so that the hours would be chronolgical, a lot of message board digging, and trial & error, but it worked!

Comment: Please try to avoid adding code to comments, instead include all relevant additions to your question, making best of code blocks. Regarding "military" time in CSV -- nope, not in my copy -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpxVX.png

Comment: Hi, thank you for all the insights, and viewpoints, gave me some ideas.  I was able to try a different method in Kaggle with POSIXct that was successful, even though it kept "NA'ing" in my RStudio files.  Perhaps I need to refresh my settings!

My apologies for the messy posts earlier, I will research the correct formatting techniques prior to posing any additional questions in the future!  Thank you again!

Comment: @Jdmor77 , you can (and should!) edit and improve your existing question.